# False warning about name can be not defined in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I wrote a python code to give a value to a variable if it is not defined, but nevertheless PyCharm warns me that the variable can be not defined:

```
if 'TEST' not in globals():
    TEST = "test"

print(TEST)
```

`Name 'TEST' can be not defined`

Is there an other way to define undefined variables such that PyCharm understand it?

Comment: Problem is with pycharm.you can ignore the warning

Comment: PyCharm can't really tell that the logic of this ensures that the name must be defined. It only looks at syntax, it can't figured out the implication of the test.

Comment: @Barmar I disagree with this because if I add the statement `else:
    TEST = globals().get('TEST')` I get rid of the warning. I think the problem comes more from the fact that we access to the variable via a string, which I find ugly but apparently there is no way to do otherwise.

Comment: @JeanPaul It has nothing to do with accessing variable through a string. It gets rid of the warning only because you provided an `else` block. PyCharm can't understand the logic `if 'TEST' not in globals()` is `False` then it is already defined

Comment: @JeanPaul Consider this piece of code: `x = 1 ; if x == 1: foo = 2 ; print(foo)` Here we also get the warning that `foo` may not be defined even though we hardcoded the condition which defines `foo` to always be `True`. Pycharm follows all possible branches according to the syntax, not logically.

Comment: I think we are on the limit of the cleverness of PyCharm, because with `if 1 == 1: foo = 2 ; print(foo)` it does not give any warning, so it could be a little bit more clever and detect that kind of implication.

Comment: @JeanPaul Anything is *possible*. But some things are harder than others. It's easy to translate `1 == 1` to `True`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a nonconditional initializer, e.g. with [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), to get rid of the warning:

```
TEST = globals().get('TEST', 'test')
print(TEST)
```

Comment: @Barmar Indeed. However using `get` *will* get rid of the warning (and the unnecessary `if`). I changed the wording a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that TEST is initialized.

```
TEST = 'TEST'
if 'TEST' not in globals():
    TEST = "test"
print(TEST)
```

Comment: The goal of my code is not to overwrite the `TEST` variable if it has been previously initialized. Explicitlly initialize it is not a solution for me, and doing so the two lines in the middle are useless.